# What is a method called if you do not use an access identifier?

Tags: c#

I do not know what a method without an access identifier is called. In this code block, I am referring to the `void updateNumTo5` method.

```
private int num = 0;

#region public methods
public int Get7()
{
    return 7;
}
#endregion

#region private methods
private int get6()
{
    return 6;
}
#endregion

#region Unknown name
void updateNumTo5()
{
   num = 5;
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default access modifier (not identifier) is `private` for methods. So this:

```
private void Foo()
{
}
```

is equivalent to

```
void Foo()
{
}
```

The general rule is that the default access modifier is always the most restricted you could specify it as. So for example, non-nested types are `internal` by default, whereas nested types are `private` by default.

Comment: Is it so irregardless of other conditions (class being public or what not)? Why have I written *private* in front of my methods all my life?!

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Yup, it's the same for all methods. I used to prefer to just leave it to the defaults, but now I make everything explicit.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I would *highly* suggest you not use the defaults here, and instead explicitly list the access modifiers.  1) the defaults vary between languages.  Start switching between developing C# and java and you could bite yourself thinking something private when it's really `package` or something like that 2) it makes the code easier to read; readers don't also need to have the defaults memorized 3) the reader may think you didn't omit it intentionally, but rather think it's a bug you forgot it; they may put something other than the default and break the code as a result.

Comment: @Servy Cool. So I **have been** doing it the right way... Well, well... I'm good even when ignorant. :)