# Default Access Level of Function

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, access-modifiers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a method called if you do not use an access identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768326/what-is-a-method-called-if-you-do-not-use-an-access-identifier)

What is the default access level for a function in VB.NET or C#?

Example:

VB.NET

```
Function GetFoo() as Foo
    Return New Foo()
End Function
```

C#

```
foo GetFoo()
{
    return new Foo();
}
```

I know that by default, classes are private. Do the member's simply inherit their parent's access level if nothing is specified?

Comment: The default on classes, structs, and interfaces is `internal`, not `private.`

Comment: Please don't close, it's not an exact duplicate. The other question makes no mention of VB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For C#, methods and fields are private by default.

For VB, methods are public by default.

Fields are trickier in VB - in structures, the default access is public, but for classes, the default access is private.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx for C# it is private.

It is under the section Class and Struct Accessibility instead of Class and Struct Member Accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Members are private by default, including other types, properties, events, methods, constructors and variables.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2(v=VS.71).aspx

Members of a class (functions) are set to private by default.